# How to apply Font color to specific cells on JTable that uses DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I'm trying to create a simple To-Do list Java application connected to MS Access and I used **JTable** and **DefaultTableModel** to display the list. I want to mark completed tasks by changing its color when I click on a button. I have a boolean field named '*completed*' that serves as indicator.

```
String header[] = {"priority", "task"};
String data[][];
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, header);
JTable table = new JTable(model);

// to be replaced with code that affects only specific cells not the whole table
table.setFont(customFont);
```

I already have a Font object that I called *customFont*, which is ready to be applied. My question is, how do I apply it only to specific cells where completed==true.

Sample codes would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- easiest of ways is look at [prepareRenderer()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9737299/714968), best of all is @camickr [Table Row Rendering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/)
- `JTable` is View, based on `TableModel`, in most cases you have to convert the view against model [converXxxToXxx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7625488/714968) from inside of `prepareRenderer` or `getTableCellRendererComponent`, because `JTable` could be sorted of filtered
- methods

code

```
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
```

returns access to the specific cell in JTable - ([TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6901508/714968))

Comment: @mKorbel, thanks for giving me a good idea and the links. I guess that's what I'm looking for... but I might still have questions soon since I'm a newbie to cell rendering.

Comment: @Mr. Xymon in most cases the easy job, but before any rendering, you have to check (if - else) row and column exist, then very simple job

Answer (score 3):

Use DefaultTableCellRenderer, then you can use setForeground() and setBackground().

refer to the page..
http://www.jyloo.com/news/?pubId=1282737395000

or see this example...

```
/*This is the raw code I have written.*/ 
JTable Tbl=new JTable(2,2){ 
    DefaultTableCellRenderer colortext=new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
    {
        colortext.setForeground(Color.RED);
    }
    @Override
    public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer(int arg0, int arg1) {
        return colortext;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can specify this behavior in

```
TableCellRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, 
                        int row, int column)
```

method of the table

Comment: It's not table method. See public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column)