# disable Combobox in jtable by click on checkbox

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, jcheckbox

I am trying to do some simple application in java.  I rendered some CheckBox and ComboBox in jTable. Now i am trying to do work on that item like getting value, Enable-disable combobox. But i am facing some problem.
What i am facing now
1.
  I render ComboBox and CheckBox in jTable. I am trying to enable ComboBox when i click on checkbox of respective row.  If my checkBox is not enable then it ComboBox should be disable.
I tried it but didn't success.

2
  I am trying to click on check box but if i use setSelected then all checkbox are checked but when i am trying to uncheck it, it didn't.
Here is my code for your reference.

```
    public class MyComboBoxRenderer extends JComboBox implements TableCellRenderer {
    public MyComboBoxRenderer(String[] items) {
        super(items);
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (isSelected) {
            setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            super.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        } else {
            setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }

        // Select the current value
        setSelectedItem(value);
        return this;
    }
   }

    public class MyComboBoxEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
    public MyComboBoxEditor(String[] items) {
        super(new JComboBox(items));
     }
   }
```

.

```
     public class MyCheckBoxRenderer extends JCheckBox implements TableCellRenderer {
     public MyCheckBoxRenderer(String[] items) {
        super();
       // setSelected(true);
     }

     public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (isSelected) {
            setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            super.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        } else {
            setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }

       // setSelected(true);
        // Select the current value

        return this;
    }
    }

    public class MyCheckBoxEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
    public MyCheckBoxEditor() {
        super(new JCheckBox());

} 
}
```

Give me some hint or reference.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

- [see my question about prepareEditor (and/or with prepareRenderer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045851/jtable-how-prepareeditor-works)
- I'd suggest to use [`prepareRenderer` (easiest and more confortable, my view)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9737299/714968) and to [check Boolean value came from Column contains (rendered as ) `JCheckBox`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6901508/714968)
- have to override [`convertXxxToModel`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7625488/714968), because `ColumnModel` [could be reordered and/or rows can be sorted or filtered](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting), in this case Renderer doesn't works correctly