# changing color of a row in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I am trying to change the color of entire row due to a column's value.

the columns I test it's value is the third one in my table.

Here is my cell rendering class code :

```
public class CustomTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
            Object obj, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                table, obj, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        String etat = (String) table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 2);
        switch (etat) {
            case "Annulé":
                cell.setBackground(Color.RED);
                break;
            case "Traitement":
                cell.setBackground(Color.yellow);
                break;
            case "Livré":
                cell.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                break;
            default : 
                // Here I want to change the color to the default color
        }
        return cell;
    }
}
```

in my test I only included three cases, and I want in the default case my row to be colored by the default color which is provided by the look & feel.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to change the color of entire row due to a column's value.

- look at [prepareRenderer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9737299/714968)
- DefaultTableCellRenderer in your form work for cell only, is required to apply renderer to whole row by using methods int row, int colum from TableCellRenderer
- `String etat = (String) table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 2);`, use [int modelRow = convertRowIndexToModel(row);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625448/jtable-removerow-removing-wrong-row/7625488#7625488), because JTables view can be sorted or filtered, then view index doesn't match to model index, (sorted or filtered)view index can living own life

Comment: +1, See [Table Row Rendering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for this and other examples when overriding the prepareRenderer() method.

Comment: To apply my rendering to the whole row I used for each column : `tcol = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
        tcol.setCellRenderer(new CustomTableCellRenderer());`

Comment: And when I used  `int modelRow = convertRowIndexToModel(row);` it shows me that :

`error: cannot find symbol
         int modelRow = convertRowIndexToModel(row);`

Comment: @user2417302 [prepareRenderer & convertRowIndexToModel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6901508/714968)