# set jtable Foreground color for some rows

Tags: java, swing, jtable, renderer

i created some costum cells render to change the look of my jtable, i changed color of some rows, and font, i tried to do the same but it doesn't work, this is my code :

```
@Override
            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
                Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
                int firstRow = 0;
                int lastRow = jTable1.getRowCount() - 1;
                if (row == lastRow) {
                    ((JComponent) c).setBackground(new Color(218, 244, 247));
                //((JComponent) c).setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12));
                } else if (row == firstRow) {
                    ((JComponent) c).setBackground(new Color(218, 244, 247));
                    ((JComponent) c).setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12));
                     ((JComponent) c).setForeground(new Color(11, 114, 126));
                } else if (row == 5) {
                    ((JComponent) c).setBackground(new Color(218, 244, 247));
                    ((JComponent) c).setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12));
                } else {
                    ((JComponent) c).setBackground(jTable1.getBackground());
                }

                return c;
            }
```

This is when i face the problem :

**((JComponent) c).setForeground(new Color(11, 114, 126));**

```
if (row == firstRow) {
((JComponent) c).setBackground(new Color(218, 244, 247));
((JComponent) c).setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12));
((JComponent) c).setForeground(new Color(11, 114, 126));}
```

Thanks

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Answer (score 1):

> , i changed color of some rows, and font, i tried to do the same but
>   it doesn't work, this is my code :

- job exactly for `prepareRenderer`, your issue must be somewhere in rest of code (as we can see your previous thread), for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about `JFrame` and `JTable` with `prepareRenderer`
- [for example the same/similair code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9737299/714968)
- but is required to override [`convertXxxToModel`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7625488/714968), because `ColumnModel` [could be reordered and/or rows can be sorted or filtered](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting), in this case index in `JTables view` is different than indexing into `XxxTableModel`, and then `XxxRenderer` doesn't works correctly

Comment: you are right, but my table shouldn't be reordered or sorted.data is from database, but with some restriction and filtring. i think Renderer will work for me (i hope so)